# When I click on Add ToDo button again and again it displays message multiple times.How can I make it only once

Tags: javascript, html

```
****You can see my code here.**
This code is on codepen**




     [Code Pen Link ][1]
```

**[1]: https://codepen.io/gurkiransinghk/pen/qBObYLR**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put p element tag and use innerHTML rather than using appenChild

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("list")
var li;


var addButton = document.getElementById("add")
addButton.addEventListener("click",addItem)

var removeButton = document.getElementById("remove")
removeButton.addEventListener("click",removeItem)

var rEverything = document.getElementById("rEverything")
rEverything.addEventListener("click",rEveryItem)

function addItem(){
    var input = document.getElementById("input")
    var ivalue = input.value;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(ivalue);

    if (ivalue == "") {
        var errorP = document.createElement("p")
        errorP.textContent = "Enter your ToDo!"
        document.querySelector(".warn").innerHTML="Enter your ToDo!";
        return false;
        
    } else {
        li = document.createElement("li")
        li.setAttribute("class","mycheck")
        li.setAttribute("class","visual")

        var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.setAttribute("id","check")

        var label = document.createElement("label")

        //addimg these elements on webpage.
        ul.appendChild(li)
        li.appendChild(checkbox)
        label.appendChild(textnode)
        li.appendChild(label)
        ul.insertBefore(li,ul.childNodes[0])

        input.value="";
    }
}

function removeItem(){
    li = ul.children
    // console.log(li)
    for (let index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
        // const element = li[index];
        // console.log(element)
        while (li[index] && li[index].children[0].checked) {
            ul.removeChild(li[index]);  
        }
    }
}

function rEveryItem(){
    li = ul.children
    for (let index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
        while (li[index]) {
            ul.removeChild(li[index])
        }
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gotu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title> Simple  ToDo Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="controls">
            <h1>My ToDo's </h1>
            <div class="para">
                <input type="text" id="input">
              <p class="warn"></p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="add">Add ToDo</button>
            <button type="button" id="remove">Remove ToDo</button>
            <button type="button" id="rEverything">Clear Whole List</button>
        </div>
        <ul id="list">
            <li class="mycheck">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check">
                <label> Gym</label>
            </li>
            <li class="mycheck">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked>
                <label>Grocery</label>
            </li>
            <li class="mycheck">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked>
                <label>Food</label>
            </li>
            <li class="mycheck">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check" checked>
                <label>Exam</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```